# Extracting a value from an object for Collectors.groupingBy(x, toSet())

Tags: java, java-stream

So, I'm trying to create a map between an id value of an object, and a set of another value within that object. The idea is that objects with each id has multiple associated types, and I need to create a way to easily reference what types are associated with the ID, within a given dataset.

For example;

```
public class exampleObj {
    public string id;
    public string type

    // getters and setters are supplied by lombok
}

Map<String, Set<String>> output = listOfExampleObj.stream().........
```

The outcome I'm looking for is a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, with the key being the id, and value being a set of the variable type, adding to the set as the stream iterates over each exampleObj

Ive tried the following, without success;

```
Map<String, Set<String>> typeMap = listOfExampleObjs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getId(), toSet(p.getType)));

Map<String, Set<String>> typeMap = listOfExampleObjs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(exampleObj::id, toSet(example::type)));

Map<String, Set<String>> typeMap = listOfExampleObjs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(exampleObj::id, groupingBy(exampleObj::type)));
```

Is there a java collector that im missing? Do I have to make a custom collector to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the answer code:

```java
ExampleObj a = new ExampleObj("1", "a");
ExampleObj b = new ExampleObj("1", "b");
ExampleObj c = new ExampleObj("2", "a");
ExampleObj d = new ExampleObj("2", "b");
ExampleObj e = new ExampleObj("3", "c");
List<ExampleObj> exps = Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d,e);
Map<String, Set<String>> typeMap = exps.stream().collect(Collectors
                            .groupingBy(ExampleObj::getId, 
                                  Collectors.mapping(ExampleObj::getType,  
                                               Collectors.toSet())));  //groupby + mapping

System.out.println(typeMap); // {1=[a, b], 2=[a, b], 3=[c]}
```